# how to get all of registered users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I get all the registered users in my course-booking system?

this is my controllers user.js

```
const User = require("../models/User") //import user model
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt") //import bcrypt
const auth = require("../auth")

module.exports.getAllUsers = (params) => {
    return User.find(params.userId).then(resultFromFind => {
        return resultFromFind
    })
}
```

and this is my routes user.js

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const UserController = require("../controllers/user")
const auth = require("../auth")

router.get('/all', auth.verify, (req, res) => {
    const users = auth.decode(req.headers.authorization)
    UserController.getAllUsers().then(user => res.send(user))
})
```

I don't know why I get this error on my console.. please help

```
GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/all 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: I am unable to pinpoint the cause, that is why not answering, but I think it may have something to do with you not passing any param to `getAllUser()` which makes `param.userID` undefined whereas to get all users you need to pass no param to `.find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `params` as a parameter of `getAllUsers()`

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const UserController = require("../controllers/user")
const auth = require("../auth")

router.get('/all', auth.verify, (req, res) => {
    const users = auth.decode(req.headers.authorization)
    UserController.getAllUsers(req.params).then(user => res.send(user)) // <------------------------
})
```